# Display data in RecyclerView from firebase: ERROR: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to display the contents of my Firebase table/list called "Assets" into a recycler view. But I am getting an error that says:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.zakatone.Assets

I have tried to look upon all the associated classes but cannot find the error.

This is how my data looks in Firebase:

[image: Database screenshot]

Assets.java

```
package com.example.zakatone;

public class Assets {
private String assetname;
private String assetamount;

public Assets() {
}


public String getAssetname() {
    return assetname;
}

public void setAssetname(String assetname) {
    this.assetname = assetname;
}

public String getAssetamount() {
    return assetamount;
}

public void setAssetamount(String assetamount) {
    this.assetamount = assetamount;
}


}
```

MyAdapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Assets> assets;

MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Assets> a)
{
    context = c;
    assets = a;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cardview,parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.name.setText(assets.get(position).getAssetname());
    holder.amount.setText(assets.get(position).getAssetamount());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return assets.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView name, amount;
    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        amount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.amount);
    }
}

}
```

This is where I am trying to display my data: overview.java

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Assets");
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.myRecycler);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Assets");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                list = new ArrayList<Assets>();
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Assets a = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Assets.class);
                    list.add(a);
                }
                adapter = new MyAdapter(overview.this,list);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(overview.this, "Something Fishy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

I want to display the data in this manner:
[image]

I am getting error in overview.java class at line:

```
Assets a = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Assets.class);
```

Please help me out as nothing is showing on the overview page at the moment. I am assuming there is an error while accessing the database table but i am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have two fields `assetName` and `assetAmount`. In Java always use `camelCase`, first word lowercase and second word starts with capital letter.

Since you have those two fields, you need to also have them in the database to be able to map the object to the database. So when saving you need to change the structure to the following:

```
Assets
   randomId
       assetName : name
       assetAmount : amt
   randomId
       assetName : name
       assetAmount : amt
```

When retrieving refer to the node `Assets` and don't use a for loop to iterate since you will retrieve the values of type `String` and not of type `Assets`

Comment: YESS okay i changed the database structure and now its displaying

Answer (score 0):

Try editing like this

```
((Assets) getActivity()).getValue;
```